# rawurlencode validation

Tags: php

I have a feeling I am overdoing this but just to guard against xss and others...

```
<?php
//will pass as get parameter to a another page
header("Location: /nextpage?p=". rawurlencode(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))));

?>
```

Comment: strip_tags does noting in your example code. once the html special chars are encoded, there will no longer be any legitimate html tags in your string. the url encoding is probably all that is needed here. I would only encode special chars either before putting it into my database, or during output to a page.

Comment: Yes, it's really to much. just do a simple `header("Location: /nextpage?p=" . filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED));` and become an happy coder.

Comment: Thanks but why is my REQUEST_URI always adding a / at the beginning of the URL?

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED)------Is this valid?